# Object variable is rendering in parentheses instead of just the content as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get an object's various properties to render in specific ways on my page.

I was writing the object variable in my code as such

```
{ ingredients[0].name }
```

But I was getting an error that the property was undefined so I changed it to the format below because I read that objects have to be enclosed in parentheses in React or it will be treated as a string which I thought was causing my error.

```
({ ingredients[0].name })
```

But now the content of the variable is being printed onto the page within parentheses. And any variable from the same object below appears to not need parentheses once the first one is given, so it is not having an issue.

```
 //only thing that appears to need parentheses, but will render with it
({ingredients[1].category}) 

     //will render as intended without parentheses, but appears to be 
     dependent on the above's parenthesis               
     <br/> ({ingredients[0].portion} 
     <br/> {ingredients[0].unit} 
     <br/> {ingredients[0].name}
```

Here is a larger snippet of my code for context as to what it looks like

```
import { ingredients } from "../file"

const Component = (props) => {
return (
 <div>
  ({ ingredients[0].category })
      <br/>
     { ingredients[0].portion } <br/>
     { ingredients[0].unit } <br/>
     { ingredients[0].name }
 </div>
)
};
```

The object variable is being imported from another page. I'll include what is on the page, although I don't think that is the source of the issue.

```
export const ingredients = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'rice wine vinegar (or sub apple cider vinegar)',
    category: 'pickled vegetables',
    portion: 2/3,
    unit: 'cup',
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'hot water',
    category: 'pickled vegetables',
    portion: 1/3,
    unit: 'cup',
},
...
```

Above is literally all of what the file has.

EDIT: I think I just didn't save the file with my variable in it, so the editor understood it as me not having anything to export.

Comment: *"so I changed it to the format below because I read that objects have to be enclosed in parentheses in React or it will be treated as a string"* No, they don't. And no, they aren't. What you have there is **text** `(` followed by a JSX expression followed by **text** `)`.

Comment: If that file really has that export, that code shouldn't do what you're describing. `ingredients[0].name` should have a value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Chrome dev says it should have a value when I created the variable and when I hover over the variable in VS Code, it indicates that it is pulling from that file which confuses me. 

So what you are saying is that it doesn't need parentheses and that my issue may be the importing of my object?

Comment: You don't need parentheses, no. I think it must be the path on the import. Do you really mean `../file` not `./file` or `./file.js`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will check the import again. If its wrong, why does VS Code act like it isn't? Act like as in, the variable isn't greyed out like it isn't active and the variable will show the objects' value pairs. I'll mess around and update you

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am still new to this site, but I wanted to thank you for your help because it led me to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I made the file with the variable in it, I didn't save it. I thought that it was saved because the VS Code editor I was using made it appear that it could import it just fine.

But because I didn't save it, I believe there was nothing for it to grab and therefore it was undefined. I must have saved the file with the variable before adding the parentheses.

Please feel free to let me know if there is an error with this conclusion or if there is something else in my code I should be mindful of so I get the most out of this learning experience.

Thank you @T.J. Crowder again for helping me figure this out!